# Rewrite rules not working as expected with apache 2.4.18

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess rewrite rule is not working please someone guide me:

[image]
my code is :

```
<Directory/>
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^signin$ signin.php
```

but still getting this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /signin was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.obsads.co.uk Port 80

Comment: try to give the full path to `signin.php`

Comment: @DhavalPurohit any example?

Comment: example `RewriteRule ^signin$ /htdocs/projectname/include/signin.php`

Comment: @DhavalPurohit still not working :( every thing is working fine on https://www.obsads.com but i want to shift site from https:www.obsads.com to http://www.obsads.co.uk but .htaccess file is now working on http://www.obsads.co.uk but working fine on https://www.obsads.com

Comment: where is your obsads.co.uk pointing?

Comment: are you using the same folder for both domains?

Comment: https://www.obsads.com is hosting on godaddy  now we buy our own server and configure obsads.co.uk on it for testing purpose if working fine then switch obsads.com from goddday to here but .htaccess is not working on it.

Comment: no no obsads.com on godaddy server, while obsads.co.uk on our server that we buy

Comment: @DhavalPurohit ???

Comment: ok then in obsads.co.uk kindly first check that if you are allowed to use the .htaccess or not by putting small redirection in the .htaccsess file. eg. `Redirect 301 / http://mt-example.com/`

Answer (score 1):

From the Apache 2.4 documentation (emphasis mine):

> The rewrite engine may be used in .htaccess files and in 
>   sections, with some additional complexity.
>
> To enable the rewrite engine in this context, you need to set
>   "RewriteEngine On" **and "Options FollowSymLinks" must be enabled**.
>   If your administrator has disabled override of FollowSymLinks for a
>   user's directory, then you cannot use the rewrite engine. This
>   restriction is required for security reasons.

So you have to enable `FollowSymLinks` in the respective context. Hopefully you are allowed to do that ...